# Roll20 reminded me of a similar program; help me identify it?

Tags: system-agnostic, tools, online-roleplaying, roll20

I was in chat here on the site and saw mention of an online tabletop gaming website called roll20.net. I have checked it out and it looks pretty promising for online play as it works in the browser, has a rolling tool in it, shows a visual of the battle map, character/monster tokens, etc.

It reminded me of a game play video I saw a while back where people were using a very similar program, so similar in fact I thought they were playing on roll20.net when I was poking around the site. However when I decided to watch some youtube videos of roll20 games it turned out that it was not the program that I remember from that gameplay video I saw months ago.

The only differences is can remember between the two programs is that the one I am failing to re-find on youtube had animated characters that were controlled in real time via the keyboard (wasd or arrow keys, I dont remember exactly what one of the guys said to the new player that asked how to control his character).

Basically, I would like to know some sites or programs that are similar to roll20.net in their functionality to make sure that if I choose to start running a game on a site like that I can choose the best one for my needs (and also to find that program I can't find the video of on youtube, tho that isn't the main focus of my request).

Comment: I have reviewed the changes... and agree with it being closed as a duplicate. I was half asleep when I posted this so A) when I searched for questions on here that could answer my question I had too narrow of a search and missed the appropriate answer. and B) I got super rambley and bogged down the question in unnecessary exposition.

Comment: Voted to reopen. This question is about a specific app, while the other is a shopping-type question. I believe the OP may be asking for the Playsets app, which is no longer available…

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of [Fantasy Grounds](http://www.fantasygrounds.com/), which does allow both players and GMs to move characters on the map.

Another one to keep your eye on is [Realm Works](http://www.wolflair.com/realmworks/), which is currently in beta.

Comment: Realm Works is more of a tool for keeping campaign details organized, though.  I don't think it is intended to fill anywhere near the same role as Roll20 et all.

Answer (score 1):

Could be Vassal (http://www.vassalengine.org). It's possible to 'build' games and skin them on Vassal, which is an online games engine. From their website:

> Vassal is a game engine for building and playing online adaptations of board games and card games. Play live on the Internet or by email. Vassal runs on all platforms, and is free, open-source software.